# What's the purpose of the IntStream.empty() method?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

During a tutorial about the new JDK8 stream API I ran across the static `.empty()` method of `IntStream`, `DoubleStream` and `LongStream`.

So when does it make sense to use this methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use to initialize an empty Stream, of any of the types mentioned by you.
I see it as a another way how to construct a new object. Simple as that.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#empty--

Answer (score 7):

A good example is to create the `IntStream` from the `OptionalInt`: you want a singleton stream if the optional is present and an empty stream if the optional is absent:

```
public static IntStream ofOptional(OptionalInt optional) {
    return optional.isPresent() ? IntStream.of(optional.get()) : IntStream.empty();
}
```

Actually such method is already [added](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/f160dec9a350/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/OptionalInt.java#l181) to JDK9.

Answer (score 4):

(You had asked about the `empty()` method on `IntStream`, `LongStream`, and `DoubleStream`, but this method is also on the `Stream` interface for reference types.)

The general answer is that `empty()` is useful as a stream source for passing to an API that takes a stream -- either as an argument or as a return value -- and when you have no values to pass. In most cases you can't pass `null`, you have to pass a stream of some sort. The way to get a stream that has no values is to use `Stream.empty()` and friends.

Here's an example that repeats even numbers and drops odd numbers and collects them into a list:

```
    List<Integer> list = 
        IntStream.range(0, 10)
                 .flatMap(i -> (i & 1) == 0 ? IntStream.of(i, i) : IntStream.empty())
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result is

```
[0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8]
```

as one would expect. The main point is that `flatMap()` passes in a single value and expects to receive an arbitrary number of values, including zero values. The way this is done is to to have the flat-mapping operation return a stream of values. To have it return zero values, it returns an empty stream.

Comment: Note that inspite you saying that "in most cases you can't pass `null`", in the particular case of `flatMap` you do can pass null.

Comment: @TagirValeev Drat, you ruined my example. :-) Null does work, but it seems much clearer to me to return an empty stream.

Comment: @StuartMarks, is this (one of the) right way to use `Optional` and `Stream.empty`?
`Optional
     .ofNullable(TransactionDataSet.getTxns(10)) // return List<>
     .map(Collection::stream).orElse(Stream.empty())
   .filter(txn -> txn.getMoney().compareTo(someAmount))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @savanibharat For this I'd suggest that `getTxns()` return an empty list instead of null if no transactions are found. Then you can just stream the list. No need to use Optional at all.